# Trouble finding IP addresses in logs

Tags: arrays, regex, bash, grep

I am trying to search a folder of over 25 log files (saved in .txt format) most of which are more than 500+MB (one is over 4.5GB) for instances of over 75 different IP's. I have tried to write a !bash script that uses an array for the IPs, but it never goes beyond the first one. Somone else suggested putting all the IPs in a txt file and then grep -f against the folder with *.txt; but though I search and search on Google, I'm not finding an example of it.
Hoping someone else here can help.. you guys have always been "wicked" smart and I've nearly always found my answer here. Thanks in advance.

Ex: (in plain english)

LOGS
Folder contains 27+ .txt files (nearly all exceeding 500MB each)
Each file has over 500,000 lines of weblog. Ex:

```
445678 14JAN13 221.33.124.321 443 192.168.1.34 /index.htm 200 juser myweb.com
```

IP_LIST = 75 unique IPs (one of which is "221.33.124.321" as taken from example above)

Need to search each file in LOGS for each IP address in IP_LIST and have output sent to `REPORT.txt` of `logfile.txt + line` Ex:

```
2013-01-14.txt
445678 14JAN13 221.33.124.321 443 192.168.1.34 /index.htm 200 juser myweb.com
```

Thanks for any help you guys can offer.

**UPDATE:**
Example of IP_LIST (aka: sourceIP.txt):

```
5.135.81.16
49.212.143.92
98.126.218.88
168.215.136.66
66.33.212.118
```

Example of content in logfile.txt (actual files are all in one directory called LogFiles and each logfile is named by YYYY-MM-DD.txt for the date it was collected - so 2013-01-01.txt, 2013-01-02.txt, 2013-01-03.txt, etc.)

--file 2013-01-01.txt--

```
66735956    2013-01-01 20:57:26.000 71.171.122.17    GHE                                                192.168.146.109  443        GET        /sites/_themes/Hello/topshape_hello.jpg  NULL                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             200    myweb\juser                            myweb.com
66735957    2014-01-01 20:57:27.000 71.171.122.17    GHE                                                192.168.146.109  443        GET        /sites/_themes/Hello/bottomshape_hello.jpg  NULL                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             200    myweb\juser                            myweb.com
66735958    2013-01-01 20:57:28.000 71.171.122.17    GHE                                                192.168.146.109  443        GET        /sites/_themes/Hello/topshape_hello.jpg  NULL                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             200    myweb\juser                            myweb.com
    middlenav.jsp
66769460    2013-01-01 17:05:38.000 66.33.212.118    NULL                                               192.168.100.89   80         GET        /wp-admin/                                         NULL                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             302    NULL                                               NULL
66769461   2013-01-01 17:05:46.000 46.165.195.139   NULL                                               192.168.100.89   80         GET        /                                                  NULL                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             200    extranet\Anonymous                                 NULL
```

--file 2013-01-03.txt--

```
66789530    2013-01-03 12:07:23.000 49.212.143.92    NULL                                               192.168.100.89   80         GET        /wp-admin/                                         NULL                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             302    NULL                                               NULL
66789531    2013-01-03 17:05:59.000 168.215.136.66   NULL                                               192.168.146.109   80         GET        /                                                  NULL                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             200    extranet\Anonymous                                 NULL
66789532    2013-01-03 17:06:44.000 46.165.195.139   NULL                                               192.168.100.89   80         GET        /                                                  NULL                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             200    extranet\Anonymous                                 NULL
```

With the very brief example above; you should be able to get an idea of how I need to only have an output to report that would say the following because the IP's in these lines matched one of the IPs from my IP_LIST.

```
2013-01-01.txt 66769460    2013-01-01 17:05:38.000 66.33.212.118    NULL                                               192.168.100.89   80         GET        /wp-admin/                                         NULL                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             302    NULL                                               NULL
2013-01-03.txt 66789530    2013-01-03 12:07:23.000 49.212.143.92    NULL                                               192.168.100.89   80         GET        /wp-admin/                                         NULL                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             302    NULL                                               NULL
2013-01-03.txt 66789531    2013-01-03 17:05:59.000 168.215.136.66   NULL                                               192.168.146.109   80         GET        /                                                  NULL                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             200    extranet\Anonymous                                 NULL
```

Hope this clears up the question being asked.
*Glenn - when I ran your script all it gave me is*

```
/cygdrive/f/LogFiles/sourceIP.txt:5.135.81.16
/cygdrive/f/LogFiles/sourceIP.txt:49.212.143.92
/cygdrive/f/LogFiles/sourceIP.txt:98.126.218.88
/cygdrive/f/LogFiles/sourceIP.txt:168.215.136.66
/cygdrive/f/LogFiles/sourceIP.txt:66.33.212.118
```

Comment: Show us what you did.  Maybe we could help you fix it!

Comment: Post some of the log files and wrap it in code format.

Comment: Please include the [relevant parts of the code](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and explain how your results differ from the desired results. Include any error messages you receive. Please read this [advice on asking good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and this blog post [Writing the perfect question](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

```
grep -Fwf IP_LIST *.txt > report.out
```

-F to match as plain strings
-w to match whole words (so the pattern "1.2.3.4" does not match 11.2.3.44)
-f IP_LIST to name the file holding the patterns.

Comment: Thanks glenn - I believe you have come the closest to what I'm attempting to do. As per Adi's comment above let me reveal what I have/get so far. (added to comment/question above after "UPDATE")

Answer (score 0):

If you like to get unique IP listed in every text file, try this bash

```
#!/bin/bash
for file in *.txt; do
awk '!a[$3]++ {c++} END {print FILENAME,c}'  $file
done
```